# Missinig provisoning profile error when building an ios ionic app using xcode 10

Tags: xcode, ionic3

I updated my version of xcode yesterday, and now when I build an ionic app that worked perfectly before I get the following error when validating the ipa:

Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision..

How can I get the embedded.mobileprovision to be generated/ included?

Thanks,
Yuval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407 has an answer, 
\just build with the --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0" and adjust project settings to build using legacy mode.

Comment: Also to upload a archive to AppStoreConnect I had to change the default build system in xcode10 within "File > Project / Workspace Settings" and change it to the legacy build system

Answer (score 21):

Currently the best workaround is to opt-out of the new build system:

If you're building on the command-line, you can specify `--buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`:

## Cordova CLI

```
cordova run ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
cordova build ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
```

## Ionic CLI

```
ionic cordova run ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

If you're building with a build.json config file, you can add the following under the iOS release or debug config:

```
"buildFlag": [
  "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
]
```

If you are opening the project in the Xcode IDE, you need to change the build system in Workspace Settings to "Legacy Build System"
[image]
[image]

Solution from [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407#issue-360392411)
Worked For Me. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this issue has been resolved with the release of cordova ios 5.0.0 ( https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/09/cordova-ios-release-5.0.0.html ) - they added compatibility with the modern build system